# Starting and Stoping weblogic services in Clustered environment

Tags: python, shell, weblogic

I want to start and stop my weblogic and clustered managed servers using a shell/python script. I did write one according to [this blog](https://www.techpaste.com/2012/04/shell-python-script-automate-weblogic-server-start-stop-running-service/). The stop script is working but the start script is not working. It says `managed server2 not found in node`.

Do I need to change any settings in node to read all the managed severs?

I tried from the blog according to my server requirements using the below blog.

When starting services it should start all the Managed servers in all the nodes successfully.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is your weblogic server version ?  if your servers are distributed among several hosts you should use the node manager. Once running in each host, you can start/stop your servers with a wlst script, called by a shell script for example.

Comment: Hello Emmanuel,  WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0

Comment: If you're using the scripts made in the example, can you provide output of the execution of the script?